# Removed program still shows up in the start menu on Mint

Tags: linux-mint, xdm

I tried uninstalling XDM and after the install the program still shows up in the start menu. Tried purging, but that cant find the process. Help me to completely remove the program

Answer (score 1):

Search through your binary directories in /usr/ and /bin/ 
Or search for the binary with :

```
$cd / 
$sudo find -type f -iname *binary name*
```

and (re-)move the file, if found out of the directory.